# Uncaught Reference Error : forge is not defiend

Tags: jquery, trigger.io, forge

i made an application with Trigger.io and  when i try to use

```
forge.request.ajax({});
```

on firubug it show me an error

on trigger :

```
[ERROR] SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string -- From line 3 of http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Uncaught Reference Error : forge is not defiend
```

i added the module forge.request and scripts

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script_index.js"></script>
```

on first time it works good but now i don't know what happened

Answer (score 0):

Forge.request.ajax will not work in firefox as the forge.request works only with trigger.io and is not a jquery function.

If you created an "App" for chrome or firefox it would work, but as a stand alone site it will not work.

If your want is to view it in the browser then you will want to use a jquery ajax request and not a forge ajax request.

Comment: i do understand, but in toolkit-local it show me an error in jquery.min.js and said that script didn't recognize forge !